# Automatically Update SQL table after 48 hours

Tags: sql-server

I need to update Table `ArticlesRequirement` set `isActive = 0` where `WriterStartDate` is over 48 hours. That is what I need to update my table after 48 hours. I also have the `starttime` and the `Experetime` in my table.

I tried:

```
update ArticlesRequirement
set  IsActive = 0, UserId = null, WriterStartDate = null, WriterExpDate = null 
WHERE WriterStartDate >= DATEADD(hour, -48, getdate())
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: `<=` should work well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `WHERE WriterStartDate <= DATEADD(hour, -48, getdate())` since datetimes in the future are larger than datetimes in the past, and you're looking for where WriterStartDate is further in the past from 48 hours ago.

<strike>To automate this, you can create a cronjob like `*/5 * * * * updatescript.sh`. That will run every 5 minutes, but you can tweak it as your liking.</strike> **edit** #&@% windows screw you